# How to get access to a child elements in Windows 8(metro) application

Tags: .net, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I have an usercontrol, that contains WebView control. And this usercontrol are placed in MainPage.xaml[MyUserControl1]. How I can get access to a WebView through my MyUserControl1?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your code with us ?
This answer is purely based upon my assumption of how you have created the user control :)

```
public class MyUserControl1: UserControl
{
    private WebView wb = new WebView();

    public MyControl()
    {
        this.Controls.Add( wb);
    }

    public WebView GetWebView
    {
        get { return wb; }
    }
 }
```

Comment: [using visual editor:D](http://screenshot.su/img/28/18/39/2818390764cbb3dd1a4007a43cd16813.jpg) of course, I can create method that returns webview, but what, when I would need access to other controls in my usercontrol? using visual editor:D of course, I can create method that returns webview, but what, when I would need access to other controls in my usercontrol?